# can use ObjectUtils.identityToString() for checking the Object null

Tags: java, apache-commons-lang3

Please find my below code that am checking for null using ternary operator before am setting the value to my bean class attributes.

```
doc.setCatalog_description(sourceAsMap != null && sourceAsMap.get("catalog_description") != null ? sourceAsMap.get("catalog_description").toString() : null);
```

Is there anyother way to simplify this code like below., Am just exploring by using `org.apache.commons.lang3.ObjectUtils;` methods. But am not sure that it is correct or not.

```
doc.setCatalog_description(ObjectUtils.identityToString(sourceAsMap.get("catalog_description")));
```

Comment: In your proposed solution if sourceMap is null then a NullPointerException will occur.

Comment: If you want to handle missing keys in sourceMap and return a default value then java 8 provides this . use `sourceMap.getOrDefault(key, defaultVal)`

Comment: Are you looking for a short way to extract catalog_description if all conditions are met? `ObjectUtils.identityToString`will return a very technical description based on the class name and the hash code of the given object. The first and the latter are different things.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the method **ObjectUtils.toString(Object)**.

```
if (sourceAsMap != null) {
    final String description = ObjectUtils.toString(sourceAsMap.get("catalog_description"));
    doc.setCatalog_description(description);
}
```

If you are using **jdk7** or higher, you can replace the method by **java.util.Objects.toString(Object)**.

```
if (sourceAsMap != null) {
    final String description = Objects.toString(sourceAsMap.get("catalog_description"));
    doc.setCatalog_description(description);
}
```

I don't know if **sourceAsMap** can be null, but if you are setting several parameters, you should check if it is null just once.

Comment: Just a note: Besides `Objects.toString(Object)` there is also `String.valueOf(Object)`.

Comment: @Izruo - so, can we use `String.valueOf(Object)` instread of `Objects.toString(Object)`..?

Comment: like this `doc.setCatalog_description(String.valueOf(sourceAsMap.get("catalog_description")));`..?

Comment: Yes, just like that, but you should improve the readability of that piece of code. For me, there are too many operations in just one line of code.

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of readability and clarity I would suggest just extracting this bit of functionality into its own method:

```
String getDescOrNull(Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap) {
    final String key = "catalog_description";
    if (sourceAsMap == null || !sourceAsMap.containsKey(key)) {
        return null;
    }
    return sourceAsMap.get(key);
}
```

then:

```
doc.setCatalog_description(getDescOrNull(sourceAsMap));
```

Answer (score 0):

> am checking for null using ternary operator before am setting the value to my bean class attributes

So I think you need to set multiple bean attributes from the map.

Best and simple solution will be to check null condition on sourceMap for once and then use ternary operator for setting attributes.

```
 if(sourceAsMap != null){
      doc.setCatalog_description(sourceAsMap.get("catalog_description") != null ? sourceAsMap.get("catalog_description").toString() : null);
      doc.setAnother_description(sourceAsMap.get("another_description") != null ? sourceAsMap.get("another_description").toString() : null);
    }
```